# How to delete the selected file from array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call the delete button to remove the listed file. Can anyone help me to build the logic.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type = "file"]').change(function (e) {
        var input = document.getElementById('fileUploader');
        var output = document.getElementById('divFiles');
        var HTML = "<table>";
        for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
            HTML += "<tr><td>" + input.files.item(i).name + "</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button ></button></td></tr>";
        }
        HTML += "</table>";
        output.innerHTML = HTML;
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Try this : 
$('table').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function(e){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove()
})

Comment: it's not working

Comment: got the result thank you for your idea   $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', "button", function (e) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
            });
        });

Comment: I am facing an another issue after selecting the files from browser again while re selecting the file the existing files were not listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the parent `tr` tag containing button delete like

```
$('.btnDelete').on('click', function () {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', "button", function (e) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
            });
        });

Comment: I am facing an another issue after selecting the files from browser again while re selecting the file the existing files were not listing.

Comment: @KavithaPrabhu `input.files` will be reset if you reupload files. If you want to keep the existing files, you can store those files in an array then rendering files from that array instead

Comment: <script>
        updateList = function () {
            var input = document.getElementById('fileUploader');
            var output = document.getElementById('divFiles');
            var filelist = new Array();
            var HTML = "<table>";
            for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
                filelist[i] = input.files.item(i).name;
                HTML += "<tr><td>" + filelist[i] + "</td><td><button ></button></td></tr>";
            } HTML += "</table>";  output.innerHTML = HTML; }

Comment: i am trying like the above code still it's not working

Comment: @KavithaPrabhu `var filelist = new Array(); ` should be placed outside method `updateList`. Otherwise it will be reset to an empty array everytime that method is called.

Comment: even after placing outside the array. same result.

Comment: @KavithaPrabhu It's just the basic idea. If you need a working solution then you should create another question for your above issue.